# Passing a variable into an SQL statement to select a specific record

Tags: java, sqlite

Okay so I have a login system, I need to pull all information in each specific users record and display it to them once logged in

```
public void info(){

    String sql = "SELECT name, surname, age, username FROM member WHERE username = 'Custom Hue'";

    try (
            Statement stmt  = connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs    = stmt.executeQuery(sql)){

        // loop through the result set
        while (rs.next()) {
            String fname = rs.getString("name");           
            String sname = rs.getString("surname"); 
            int age = rs.getInt("age");       
            String uname = rs.getString("username");

            lblFName.setText(fname);
            lblSName.setText(sname);
            lblAge.setText(String.valueOf(age));
            lblUName.setText(uname);
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }


}
```

Above: I get all the information I need and disaplyed correctly but only if I put the specific users name from the database into the query

I have this code which displays the users username in a label pulled from the login stage

```
    public void GetUser(String user) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    usernameLabel.setText("Welcome back, " + user + "!");
}
```

Is there a way in which I could push the GetUser method or place the usernameLabel where I currently have the 'Custom Hue'

Comment: Read the documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Comment: [Using prepared statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand you are need this?

```
    public void info(String userName){

    String sql = "SELECT name, surname, age, username FROM member WHERE username = ?";

    try (
            PreparedStatement stmt  = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
            stmt.setString(1, userName);
            ResultSet rs    = stmt.executeQuery(sql)){

        // loop through the result set
        while (rs.next()) {
            String fname = rs.getString("name");           
            String sname = rs.getString("surname"); 
            int age = rs.getInt("age");       
            String uname = rs.getString("username");

            lblFName.setText(fname);
            lblSName.setText(sname);
            lblAge.setText(String.valueOf(age));
            lblUName.setText(uname);
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    }
```

Comment: It should only retrieve information of the currently logged in user

Comment: Sure, this function just get information of the user that you want, you want which user then pass the `userName` into this method

Comment: I don't think this code compiles because a plain `Statement` cannot hold bind variables; you need a `PreparedStatement` for that.

Comment: @MickMnemonic thanks for you comment, I have forgot to check the code

Comment: Looking better now!